# Ler 9 números inteiros, ordenar de forma decrescente e inserir numa matriz 3x3

Tags: javascript

### Tentativa de código:

```
function getRandom(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * max + 1)
}

function criarMatrizAlt(n){ 
    const mat = Array(n).fill(undefined).map(x => Array(n).fill(getRandom(10)));   
    mat.sort(function(a,b){
        if(a > b) return 1;
        if(a < b) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
    return mat; 
}

console.log(criarMatrizAlt(3));
```

### Saída:

`[ [ 9, 9, 9 ], [ 3, 3, 3 ], [ 2, 2, 2 ] ]`

**OBS.:** preciso de ajuda em como **ler os valores pelo navegador (com prompt ou algo do tipo) e então armazenar os valores na matriz.**

Comment: Opa Bruno, veja se seria isto por favor: https://jsfiddle.net/xy9z36oc/

Comment: @MarceloVismari muito obrigado, Marcelo!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Resolução pessoal:

```
<!-- Faça uma programa que receba 9 números inteiros e armazene os em ordem decrescente em uma matriz de 3x3 -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title> Ordenando uma matriz </title>
    <script>
        let array = new Array();
        for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            dados = prompt("N" + i + ": ");
            array.push(dados);
            array.sort(function (a, b) {
                if (a < b) return 1;
                if (a > b) return -1;
                return 0;
            });
        }

        const matriz = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i = i + 3) {
            matriz.push(array.slice(i, i + 3));
        }
        console.log(matriz);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Saída esperada:

[image: Matriz com ordenação decrescente]